# Rendering to a texture using the image API (no Framebuffer)

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-4

As an experiment I decided to try rendering to a texture using the image API exclusively.  At first the results were obviously wrong as the texture write occurred before the depth test.  So I enabled the `early_fragment_tests`, which I though was introduced for pretty much this type of use case, but now I get a weird sort of flickering which seems like Z-fighting, which seems strange since it should be performing the same depth test that works for regular rendering.

Anyway, I've included an image of the problem, and I'm curious if anyone has an explanation as what is going on, and why this doesn't work.  Can it be made to work?

[image: Flickering Dwarf]

Here's a minimal reproducer

```
    #version 420
    in vec3 normal;
    layout(binding = 0) writeonly uniform image2D outputTex;
    void main()
    {
        vec4 fragColor = vec4(normal, 1);
        imageStore(outputTex, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), fragColor);
    }
```

Comment: What "image API" are you talking about? Also, adding some code would help.

Comment: `ARB_shader_image_load_store`

Comment: So... what does your code look like? There are many ways to use Image Load/Store operations incorrectly, and there's no way to know which ones you did without seeing the code.

Comment: Basically where I would write the fragment color out I simply use an `imageStore(outputTex, ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy), fragColor);` to write to a texture.  The only other change is the `layout(early_fragment_tests) in;` at the top of the file.

Comment: By "what does your code look like," I meant "Post your code". Not a fragment of your code. Put your code in the question where people can see it.

Comment: Here's the thing. I would very much like to help. From your description of your code, I have a few ideas of what might be causing the problem. However, without seeing your actual code, I can't *know* which one of them is the problem. And I'm not posting a bunch of *guesses* as to what *might* be going on. Questions on SO should be self-contained enough that, if you post an answer, you have some reasonable assurance that it's actually right without the OP coming along later to say whether it is right or not.

Comment: Added minimal reproducing code

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make some assumptions about the code you didn't show. Because you didn't show it. I'm going to assume that:

1. You used [proper memory coherence operations](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Memory_Model#Ensuring_visibility) when you went to *display* this image (whether to the actual screen or in a `glReadPixels`/`glGetTexImage` operations).
2. You rendered this scene using a regular rendering command, with no special ordering of triangles or anything. You did not render each triangle with a separate rendering command with memory coherence operations between each.

In short, I'm going to assume that your problem is actually due to your shader. It may well be due to many other things. But since you didn't deign to show the rest of your code, I can't tell. Therefore, this answer may not in fact answer your problem. But garbage in, garbage out.

The problem I can see from your shader and the above assumptions is really quite simple: [incoherent memory accesses (like image load/store)](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Memory_Model#Incoherent_memory_access) are *completely unordered*. You performed an image write operation. Therefore, you have no guarantees about this write operation unless you take steps to make those guarantees.

Yes, you used early fragment tests. But that doesn't mean that the order of incoherent memory accesses from your fragment shader will be in any particular order.

Consider what happens if you render a triangle, then render a triangle in front of it that completely covers it. Early fragment tests won't change anything, since the top fragment happens after the bottom one. And image load/store does not guarantee *anything* about the ordering of writes to the same pixel. Therefore, it is very possible for writes to the bottom triangle to complete after writes to the top triangle.

As far as I know, ordering writes to the same pixel from different fragment shaders like this is not possible. Even if you issued a `memoryBarrier` after your write, my reading of the spec doesn't suggest that this will guarantee the write ordering here.

The correct answer is to not do this at all. Write to fragment shader outputs; that's what they're there for.

Comment: Like I said, this was an experiment. I learned that there is additional logic required beyond the early fragment tests required to perform a correct rendering.  Whether that functionality can be reproduced with atomics or something I've yet to discover. At the moment I don't have time for more experiments.  But yes, when I'm not experimenting, framebuffers and fragment outputs are what I use.